# Flutter SQFLITE how to remove an entry matching TWO fields

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

```
   await _database!.delete(
    "row",
    where: "id = ?",
    whereArgs: [id],
  );
```

I want to remove an entry based on both ID and DATETIME,

something like this;

```
      await _database!.delete(
    "row",
    where: "id = ?" && "DateTime = ?", <----- Doesn't actually work
    whereArgs: [id, day],
  );
```

How do I go about doing this? .delete only accepts a single string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you just pass the SQL WHERE part of the command there as a single string:

```
where: "id = ? AND DateTime = ?"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using and

```dart
await _database!.delete(
    "habits",
    where: "id = ?" and "DateTime = ?", 
    whereArgs: [id, day],
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
await _database!.delete(
    "row",
    where: "id = ? AND DateTime = ?",
    whereArgs: [id, day],
  );
```

Comment: That is the same answer I gave 10 minutes earlier.